# Ext.direct buffer

Tags: extjs

I have a question about Ext.direct.addProvider.
I am using a remoter provider.
I know there is an option to add buffer for multiple requests.
But what i am looking for is a buffer that waits for XXX amount of time, and only then sends the request.
Also, is there a way to send the request when a user clicks on a button ?

Thx,
Yoni

Answer (score 1):

okay, i found an attribute enableBuffer which you can specify an XXX amount of time to send the request.

for the second question, is there a way to send the request when a user clicks on a button ?

Yoni